# Spark SQL – how to group by or aggregate with dynamically generated keys?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a DataFrame of overlapping **ordered** arrays.

```
[1,2,3]    
[2,3,4]    
[7,8,9]
```

Using Spark SQL I would like to group those that overlap, like below:

```
Key  Values 
1    [1,2,3], [2,3,4] 
2    [7,8,9]
```

I was looking into `UDAF` functions, but can't understand how can I generate a new key for those rows that match my merging criteria.

Currently, I implemented it on the driver side, like this:

1. Order the collection of arrays by their first and last elements.
2. In a loop, if the first element in the array is less or equal than the last element of the previous array, then put them in the same bucket.

This works, but to do that I need to collect all the data on the driver side and I'm looking for a more efficient way to do that.

Comment: by overlapping, do you mean "having at least one common element" or overlapping by range? if the first one, then your way is wrong. consider [1, 7] and [2, 5]. they have no common elements but you're going to put them into the same bucket

Comment: @mangusta, the second one (overlapping by range)

Comment: even in that case, looking at the previous array only is not enough. for example, you have a collection of arrays sorted by first element (btw unclear why it should be sorted by last too): [1,2,3,4,5,6], then [2,3], then [4,5]. you look at [2,3], 2 < 6, so you put them into some bucket. then you look at [4,5]. it does not overlap with 2nd array but it overlaps with 1st one.

Comment: Before I post answer I have in my mind, could you please address questions posted by @mangusta I feel that this question fails to address all the cases for relatively complex scenario.

Comment: @D3V, mangusta - for that reason I also order by last element. Suppose [1,2,3,4],[1,2,3],[4,5,6] - if I don't order by last element then [4,5,6] will go in a separate bucket. In a loop I also have extra var as a set, where I merge values of each bucket and compare against that set. I agree the logic is a bit confusing, though I don't care much about details. I just hoped someone could point in the right direction on how to merge or group rows of dataframes iteratively and not knowing the grouping key in advance. Maybe I should look not in the groupBy and Agg functions, but into something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I could implement to help with the situation.
Explanation:

1. Find permutations first for array which have length greater than 1
2. Explode permutation array
3. group by on permutation array and collect list of original array
4. Get distinct of list of original array

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val y = sc.parallelize(Seq(Seq(1,2,3),Seq(2,3,4),Seq(7,8,9))).toDF("arr")
val x = (s:Seq[Int]) => s.toSet[Int].subsets.filter(_.size>1).map(_.toList).toList
val permutations = udf(x)
val a = y.select($"arr", permutations($"arr").as("permutations"))
a.select($"arr", explode($"permutations").as("permutations")).groupBy("permutations").agg(collect_set($"arr").as("groups")).select($"groups").distinct().select(monotonicallyIncreasingId, $"groups").show(false)

//+-----------------------------+----------------------+
//|monotonically_increasing_id()|groups                |
//+-----------------------------+----------------------+
//|214748364800                 |[[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]]|
//|412316860416                 |[[7, 8, 9]]           |
//|884763262976                 |[[1, 2, 3]]           |
//|1056561954816                |[[2, 3, 4]]           |
//+-----------------------------+----------------------+
```

I hope this will get you started. There are a lot of nitty-gritties, I will leave those to you.

Comment: That's what I need. Thanks a lot!